# How do you interpret $\chi^2$ p-values for a logistic regression, i.e.when R outputs the p-values sequentially with anova(model,test= Chisq)?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, p-value, chi-squared-test, interpretation

How would you interpret this output:

```
anova(mlogistic1, test = "Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: obese

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                    7965    1030.38             
sex     1   14.227      7964    1016.16 0.000162 ***
educa1  3   13.913      7961    1002.24 0.003027 ** 
phyact  2   13.226      7959     989.02 0.001343 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
anova(mlogistic2, test = "Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: over

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                    7965     5250.9              
sex     1   22.787      7964     5228.1 1.810e-06 ***
educa1  3  202.321      7961     5025.8 < 2.2e-16 ***
phyact  2   30.619      7959     4995.2 2.245e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```